# Canceling async call in property

Tags: c#, mvvm, async-await, uwp

I am developping an UWP MVVM application which resolving adress with location :

```
private async void ResolveAddress()
{
    //TODO : Manage cancel
    Debug.WriteLine("Resolving adress ...");
    var result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(SelectedLocation);
    if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
    {
        if (result.Locations.Count > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Adress resolved : " + Address);
            Address = result.Locations[0].Address.FormattedAddress;
        }
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("Resolve fail");
}
```

This call can occured really often (based on the location selected by the user), so the method may have not finishing running when an other call is make.

```
//Binding property
public Geopoint SelectedLocation
{
    get { return _selectedLocation; }
    set
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Location change");
        _selectedLocation = value;
        ResolveAddress();
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

The Adress field is also a binding property.

I encounter 2 problems with this implementation :

- I am not sure the Adress field will the last selected location (the call N-1 can finished after N).
- The adress field contains progressivly all the adress resolved I want only the the last.

I find a way to cancel async task :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/jj155759.aspx

But the MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync does not have a cancelation token in parameters.

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Calling a Async function on your property set is not a good practice. Try to change that any event . Either On `SelectionChanged` Event is best place to do this

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure the Adress field will the last selected location (the call N-1 can finished after N).

You can solve this with an [asynchronous callback token](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/asynchronous-callback-contexts.html). I describe it in more detail in a very old blog post where I call them "asynchronous callback contexts". Given how overloaded the term "context" is today, I now prefer the term "token".

```
private object _addressCallbackToken;

private async void ResolveAddress()
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Resolving adress ...");
  var token = _addressCallbackToken = new object();
  var result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(SelectedLocation);
  if (token != _addressCallbackToken)
    return;
  if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
  {
    if (result.Locations.Count > 0)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("Adress resolved : " + Address);
      Address = result.Locations[0].Address.FormattedAddress;
    }
  }
  Debug.WriteLine("Resolve fail");
}
```

However, I strongly recommend not using `async void` in this fashion. You may find my article on [async MVVM data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn605875) useful.